# How to get 'Shopping Behavior Analysis' in google anlaytics using google tag manager for magento sites

Tags: magento, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using Google tag manager in order to implement Enhanced ECommerce for a magento site, I have tried the 'universal tag' with track type 'Transaction' with the following rule

[image]

I get the result of "Product Performance" and "Sales Performance" however i am not getting any result for 'Sessions with Product Views,Add to Cart,Transaction' for "Shopping Behavior analysis" I have also tried it using datalayer push method for product view page as

```
dataLayer.push({
'event': 'productDetails', 
'ecommerce': {
    'detail': {

        'products': [{
        'name': ProductName,         
        'id': id


         }]
     }
 }});
```

which shows the datalayer after the event is fired but the shopping behavior still does not change.

So is there any other way using which i can get proper data in my GA for shopping behavior in enhanced ecommerce.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use transaction type at all when using enhanced ecommerce. Here is the guide https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#details